# how to restrict the keyboard to appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have designed a keyboard on my app Now I have the query is that whenever somebody tap on the textfield the keyboard on the device appear which i don't want
is there any way to disable the keyboard so that the user can see the keyboard designed on this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ViewController` add the delegate of the `UITextField` :

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

While Creating the `UITextField` or in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
self.myTextField.delegate = self;
```

In your implementation file:

```
 #pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return NO;
}
```

Note that you can set the return of `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` to NO or YES according to your needs, in your case you may return  YES , but provide the logic of displaying your custom keyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return NO;
}
```

And Needs to add delegate `<UITextFieldDelegate>`

In this method you also can write code to show your custom keyboard.

lol

Comment: thanx chetan for your answer but this is the basic approach.. I have tried that at the very first go however its not working.

Comment: do you have set delegate of textfield to view controller in storyboard?

Comment: yes i have and i am also calling 1 more function inside textFieldShouldBeginEditing. so everything is working fine... its just that the device's inbuilt keyboard is coming which i dont want i want to use my own designed keyboard.

Comment: @Sandra did you take the time to check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `inputView` to a zero sized view:

```
textField.inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach to restrict keyboard display when user tap on it :

**Method : 1**

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    return NO; 
}
```

This method hide the Keyboard and dont show the cursor.

**Method : 2**

```
UIView* HideView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)] autorelease];    
textField.inputView = HideView;
```

This method hide the Keyboard, but Cursor is appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable user interaction.

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```